# Is there any diffeomorphism from $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any diffeomorphism from $(a,b)$ and  $\mathbb{R}$ which is $(1)$ polynomial and $(2)$ a rational $(3)$ transcendental ?

---

The third one is obviously  $\tan x$ but I think first one is not possible but I don't have the proof. Also want an example for the second one.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial is continous over R, so is bounded on every [a,b] then on every (a,b), hence it cannot be a diffeomorphism from (a,b) to R

For the rationnal fraction, something like $\frac{x-\frac{a+b}{2}}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ should work